# PHP Mailer - Links inside email not working on IOS or Mac OS

Tags: php, macos, email, hyperlink, phpmailer

I'm sending mail using PHP mailer that has links in it, the links are working fine on windows and android but when it comes to Apple devices the links are rendered as applewebdata:// and is not working properly.

I've read that it might be because the links don't have protocols in them but I have https:// written on the links. Any suggestions?

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('example@email.com', 'Example');
$mail->addAddress($email);
$mail->"Subject";
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->Body    =  $message ."<br> <a href='https://www.example.com'>Link</a>";
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->send();
```

Comment: Let's start by the beginning, without code we cannot help you. Can you show us (the essential part of) the code you are using? For example, a link you are using (can be changed), the complete text you are using and the code you are using to send it all together.

Comment: @TomUdding Added code block

Comment: I've seen this happen - I think it's a bug in Apple Mail. I've also seen some links work but not others within the same message.